# check set equality on modification of sets

Tags: python

How would i be  able to use sets in python write a program that accepts 2 words from the user and does the following checks.If after placing both words into sets they are equal then print equal otherwise not equal.I am learning python and in this book it gives examples of sets and mentioned this but gave no code so can someone help me visualise this so i can learn it , any help is much appreciated

Comment: By “placing both words into sets” do you mean creating a single-element set containing just the word, or creating a set of all of the unique letters in the word, or something different?

Answer (score -1):

```
#accept two words
word1 = input()
word2 = input()

#add them to set
set1.add(word1)
set2.add(word2)

#check for equality
if set1 == set2:
    print('equal')
else:
    print('not equal')
```

If you instead want to check if the sets are of equal length replace the if statement by:

```
if len(set1) == len(set2)
```

Comment: it kept giving an error code when i typed in 'set1' or 'set2' anywhere